# Counting consecutive numbers into one row

Tags: oracle

I have recently discovered that we can use Max ( Decode ()) function of Oracle to pivot the results of a table. I have executed this just fine. However, pivoting a table is just one part of the solution that I need. The pivoting function results to something like this:

```
01,02,03,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,20,21,23,25
```

What I actually need is something like this:

```
1-17, 20-21,23,25
```

I really don't know how to start solving this but so far I have the below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'01', '01')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'02', ',02')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'03', ',03')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'04', ',04')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'05', ',05')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'06', ',06')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'07', ',07')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'08', ',08')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'09', ',09')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'10', ',10')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'11', ',11')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'12', ',12')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'13', ',13')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'14', ',14')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'15', ',15')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'16', ',16')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'17', ',17')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'18', ',18')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'19', ',19')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'20', ',20')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'21', ',21')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'22', ',22')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'23', ',23')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'24', ',24')) 
      || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'25', ',25'))  AS WAFERS      
      , 'history' as well
FROM a_wiplothistory wl
JOIN Container C ON (wl.containerid = c.containerid OR wl.containerid= c.splitfromid )
JOIN a_wiplotdetailshistory wld ON wl.wiplothistoryid = wld.wiplothistoryid
JOIN a_wiplotdetailswafershistory wldw ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = wldw.wiplotdetailshistoryid
WHERE c.containername = :lot
```

Thanks for helping guys.

Comment: It would be better to use `case ~ when` for complex conditions.

Comment: hello ntalbs, can you give me a sample on how I can start this?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. If you want to reduce consecutive numbers to range (ex: 01,02,03 -> 1-3, and 02,03,04 -> 2-4), then `case ~ when` wouldn't help you.

Comment: thanks anyway ntalbs :) you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 MAX(CASE WHEN wldw.wafernumber BETWEEN '01' AND '17' THEN '01-17' END)
  || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'18', ',18')) 
  || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'19', ',19')) 
  || MAX(CASE WHEN wldw.wafernumber IN ('20','21') THEN '20-21' END) 
  || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'21', ',21')) 
  || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'22', ',22')) 
  || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'23', ',23')) 
  || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'24', ',24')) 
  || MAX(DECODE(wldw.wafernumber,'25', ',25'))  AS WAFERS      
  , 'history' as well
```